# How to calculate the exact parameters of the increased reduction formula Atempo and Pitch with Ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I've got content that was originally 23.976 sped up to 29,97 for european distribution. I need to shift / correct the audio pitch back down to normal without affecting the timing. Is there a filter for FFmpeg that can accomplish this task? I've been reading through the online documentation for things like atempo and asetrate but they don't seem to .Do what I need.
And I have the formula to calculate the percentage increase or decrease pitch and Atempo audio :

```
-af asetrate=r=23.97/1001/29.97*<currentrate>,atempo=29.97*1001/23.97
```

I don't understand **< currentrate >**, below is the video information.

[video information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Btgxo.png)

And, example:

> asetrate=r=52 , the Atempo = ? and features such as certain formula ?

Comment: Is the current audio shorter and needs to have only pitch corrected?

Comment: when I render the sound does not match the image although the timing of the video input = time video output.

info video input: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Btgxo.png

Comment: Is the audio slower or faster?

Comment: audio slower, video faster

Comment: standard formula is calculated when increased asetrate = r = 52 , Atempo = ? ( Original video frame rate = parameter 23.97 ) . I want to increase the frame rate up to 29.97 ?

Comment: This is just for the audio. Try `asetrate=44100/0.8,aresample=44100`.

Comment: Atempo speed and slow?

Comment: I don't understand the formula that are exactly like what ? this is their original article : https://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2015-March/025808.html

Comment: As their formulas , the Atempo = 25 * 1001/24000 == > Atempo = 1.0427
and asetrate = r = 24000/1001 / 25 * < currentrate > == > **"asetrate = r = 24000/1001 / 25 * ?"**

Comment: You "shouldn't" need to adjust the audio at all, since all you're doing is adjusting the video fps, yes?